# How do I install Heroku CLI on Termux?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, termux

Termux is a Linux terminal emulator for Android. I want to install the Heroku CLI to be able to manage my Heroku apps on the go, I tried typing `heroku` to prompt the error message and link to the right package, but it gives me:

```
No command 'heroku' found, did you mean:
 Command 'heyu' from package 'heyu'
```

I tried installing the CLI from the official website, but that didn't work out as well. What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the npm package [heroku](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku), its the complete CLI as what you find from the official website. Simply do

```
npm i -g heroku
```

---

Alternatively, you may use yarn. Install yarn by doing

```
pkg install yarn
```

and then install the Heroku CLI by

```
yarn add global heroku-cli@latest
```

Comment: Thank you Priit Balagopal, this solution works using termux